# "Argument type string does not conform to expected type decoder" when trying to get JSON using codable protocol

Tags: swift, codable

I'm trying to use Swift 4 `Codable` feature to get JSON but for some reason it creates an error that says:

> Argument type string does not conform to expected type decoder

Here is my code:

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

```
import UIKit

struct aURL : Codable {
    let title: String
    let aurl: String
    //    let style: URLStyle
}

 class SectionTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    do {
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "cool")
        queue.async {

            if let somedata = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(from: "http://json-schema.org/example/geo.json")!, options: []) {

                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: somedata, options: [])
                print(json)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                }
            }

        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

and if I try to fix it using Xcode suggested fix as shown in the image:

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

I get this error:

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String' (0x1015acf68) to 'Swift.Decoder' (0x1015ec460).

Answer (score 3):

There is a misunderstanding.

The `URL` API

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
```

can **only** be used **within** the custom struct to create an URL from a given `Decoder` very similar to the `init(coder` API of the class related `NSCoding` protocol.

---

In the context to create an URL *from* a string you have to use `URL(string`

```
URL(string: "http://json-schema.org/example/geo.json")!
```

That's exactly what the error message says: ***I'm expecting a `Decoder` but I'm getting a `String`***

---

Important note:

**Never** load data from a remote URL with the synchronous API `Data(contentsOF:` – not even in an asynchronous dispatch queue – and don't carelessly ignore errors with `try?`